Drag-Drop - prevent placeholder creation - keep original
I have a mat table that supports nested tree lists where I allow drag drop (reordering disabled) to drag row on top of each other. The problem is that I need events on each table row. But when a row is dragged, it's replaced by a html duplicate, the placeholder, that does not have any events attached and does not update it's classes:
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getColumns()"
    cdkDrag
    [cdkDragDisabled]="!this.allowDragDrop || this.isEditing(row.item)"
    [hidden]="!this.isPathToRootExpanded(row)"
    [ngClass]="this.getTableRowClasses(row.item)"
    (click)="this.toggleSelection(row.item)"
    (cdkDragStarted)="this.onDragStarted(row.item)"
    (mouseenter)="this.updateDropTargetRow(row.item, false)"
    (mouseleave)="this.updateDropTargetRow(row.item, true)"
    (mousemove)="this.onDragMouseMove($event)">
</tr>

In this stackblitz prototype you can reproduce the problem. The dragged row does not get the hover-center highlight nor the indicators above or below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zutvxk
I want to keep the original row and don't want a placeholder.

When I drag a row in your stackblitz example, it does show an indicator as to where it would be placed. What exactly do you mean with he dragged row does not get the hover-center highlight nor the indicators above or below?

If you drag QMB and hover THE ROW QMB it does not get highlighted. Any other row gets highlighted. Also the indicator only shows up when you hover any other row. So the classes drop-above, drop-below and drop-center are not applied to the row QMB when its dragged. That's because its a placeholder that does not have the row events because it's only a html clone
